# MySQL - Find pairs in either column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a VERY large table called `fullNames`:

```
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| id | name1     | name2    | count  |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| 1  | Homer     | Simpson  |   2    | <-- Homer clicked Simpson's name 2 times
| 2  | Bart      | Simpson  |   1    | <-- Bart clicked Simpson's name once
| 3  | Simpson   | Bart     |   4    | <-- Simpson clicked Bart's name 4 times
......................................
......................................
| 80 | Steven    | Baldwin  |   7    | <-- Steven clicked Baldwin's name 7 times
| 81 | Alec      | Baldwin  |   6    | <-- Alec clicked Balwin 6 times, but there's NO relationship w/ Steven's clicks
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Essentially I need to be able to determine how many times the given user (`name1`) has clicked on a given name (`name2`), then determine the opposite - how many times `name2` has clicked on `name1`. When Simpson loads up his page, he should see a list of names put in order based on the combined `count`s of matching pairs that include his name. That list would look like this:

```
Bart       5
Homer      2
```

When there's a click, I can insert it into the table no problem, BUT I don't know how to query for something like this... I guess it would ultimately need to come out as a JSON object/array so this can be made into a native mobile app, so bonus points if you feel like working that out too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Simpson`, you want to include rows where either name is "Simpson", but the name you want to select (and count for) is the "non-Simpson" name. You can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Name1 <> 'Simpson' THEN Name1 ELSE Name2 END AS ClickName,
  SUM(count) AS ClickCount
FROM fullNames
WHERE 'Simpson' IN (Name1, Name2)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Name1 <> 'Simpson' THEN Name1 ELSE Name2 END
ORDER BY ClickCount DESC
```

Comment: So I guess this is more efficient than the first answer was? It certainly looks good to me, but that doesn't mean much! Thanks a ton!

Comment: My previous answer was plainly wrong (I misunderstood your need). Now I couldn't tell for sure which of the two options works best, but you may want to try both.

Comment: No problem - but note I made a fix to the query: I typed the `count` column as `COUNT(*)`; kinda on auto-pilot there. The updated query should be fine.

Comment: Because the only custom info we have for input is the user's name `simpson`, the ClickName (the name we DIDN'T know, the name that's stored in the database) is the name we want to retrieve. As it is now, this brings up the name "Simpson" - how would you modify it to bring up the other name? I swapped Name1 & Name2 at the top, which worked, but without understanding the SQL fully, I don't know if the other `THEN Name1 ELSE Name2` needs to also be switched to `THEN Name2 ELSE Name1`... Thanks! Oh and for the record, I had to change the columns in my table so that they were indexed as unique.

Comment: Yes - you should swap the other. The CASE in the GROUP BY should be identical to the CASE in the SELECT. The index is no problem; it may even make the query run faster.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, this SQL is perfect, I just mistakenly added quotes to my PDO items/objects/variables/whatever... Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I was wondering at the time, but it was near the end of day for me so I let it go and then forgot about it. I'm glad this worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the results from the database:

```
SELECT name, SUM(`count`)
FROM (
    -- records where "your_input_name" is the clicker
    SELECT name2 AS name, `count`
    FROM fullNames
    WHERE name1 = "your_input_name"

    UNION

    -- records where "your_input_name" is the "clickee"
    SELECT name1 AS name, `count`
    FROM fullNames
    WHERE name2 = "your_input_name"
) AS sub
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184655/pulling-data-from-mysql-into-json-array) will show you how to parse the result and convert it as a JSON string, ready to be sent to your application.